# Clang loop optimizations causes a segmentation fault?

Tags: c, clang

I was writing code for "binary search". And meanwhile I did, I wrote some code to see where my start, middle, and end point is. For that I printed out a string where the numbers for start, middle and end were surrounded by square brackets. Because that lead me to a segmentation fault, I made a copy of the code and condensed it to the smallest amount of code which causes the issue.

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    int values[9] = {1, 3, 6, 9, 10, 14, 16, 17, 21};
    int n = sizeof(values) / sizeof(int); // <-- make this is a "const", and the "segmentation fault" goes away

    char buf[20] = "";
    char num[6] = "";

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("i: %i, n: %i\n", i, n);

        sprintf(num, "[%i] ", values[i]);

        strcat(buf, num);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with this line:

```
clang -std=c99 -Wall -Werror loop.c -o loop
```

Somehow "n" get changed, despite it shouldn't get changed. At least it is not changed by me.

So why does this happen?

Comment: By the way, do not take the down vote personally. I did not vote, but I imagine the voter voted because this question is not hugely useful for other people—it is not something that is likely to be what they are searching for when looking up their own problem. You did a good job reducing the problem to a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

You declared `buf` as an array of 20 `char`, but you write “[1] [3] [6] [9] [10] [14] [16] [17] [21]” to it, which is 41 `char`, including the terminating null. During the loop, `strcat` overruns `buf` and writes data to memory it should not, which corrupts other things in your process.

Comment: Okay. That makes sense. But why does making „n“ a const fix this?

Comment: @IkemKrueger: Making `n` const does not fix the problem. It just happened to cause the compiler to change how it organized things in memory, with the result that the buffer overrun destroyed different data than before, in a way that might not have been noticeable in your program’s observable behavior.

Comment: Undefined Behavior can be tricky in that way.  If you move the declaration of `n` to be after all of your buffers, it also happens to not segfault (at least on my system).  Use of safer functions like `strncat` can help you avoid buffer-overflows by specifying the length of the buffer.

Comment: And one last note as relates to `strcat`, using it in a loop like this can be rather inefficient because it has to recalculate the length of the string each time it is called, and as the string grows, so does the amount of time to calculate its length.  This is referred to as a Sclemiel The Painter algorithm. https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/schlemiel_the_painter%27s_algorithm .  It is better to keep track of the length of the string as you go and then you can use that as an offset into the buffer to copy directly to the end of the string instead of costly recalculation of its length.